# Animating UIView Header - Disable Scrolling while Animating

Tags: uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

So I'm trying to have it so my headerView, which is just a regular `UIView`, animates up and out-of-view as soon as the user scrolls up, but if the user scrolls down then it just scrolls down normally without animation. It seems to work but with one issue - because the `UIScrollView` is bouncing while it scrolls up, this causes the direction to switch, and the animation seems to get interrupted.

FIX?: I'm thinking a fix would be that once the animation starts, I disable capturing the scroll until it completes - but I don't know how to do that.

NOTE: So my `UIScrollView` is a `childVC` in a `tableVCContainerView`. The `headerView` and this `tableVCContainerView` are both `subviews` of an overall `containerView`. I don't think this is part of the problem I'm trying to solve, but I wanted to make a note of it.

- (void)childScrollViewDidScroll:(NSNotification *)note {

  ```
  UIScrollView* scrollView = [[note userInfo] valueForKey:kWSAccountVCChildDidScrollScrollViewKey];

  CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
  CGFloat scrollWindow = self.headerView.frame.size.height-kWSWordlistDividerViewHeight;


  __block CGRect containerFrame;


  // Only animate if scrolling up
  if (self.lastOffset.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y && self.containerView.frame.origin.y > -scrollWindow) {

      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{

          containerFrame = self.containerView.frame;

          containerFrame.origin.y = -scrollWindow;

          self.containerView.frame = containerFrame;

      } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

          self.lastOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

      }];

  }
  else {

      containerFrame = self.containerView.frame;

      containerFrame.origin.y = -scrollOffset;

      self.containerView.frame = containerFrame;

      self.lastOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, containerFrame.origin.y);


  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

So I put a flag in isAnimatingHeaderView, which was the obvious solution to disable any scroll capturing while animating. This code works like any other code here for the numerous questions that ask how to animate headers up/down:

```
- (void)childScrollViewDidScroll:(NSNotification *)note {

UIScrollView* scrollView = [[note userInfo] valueForKey:kWSAccountVCChildDidScrollScrollViewKey];

CGFloat scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
CGFloat scrollWindow = self.headerView.frame.size.height-kWSWordlistDividerViewHeight;


__block CGRect containerFrame;


if (isAnimatingHeaderView) {
    return;
}

// Only animate if scrolling up
if (self.lastOffset.y < scrollOffset && self.containerView.frame.origin.y > -scrollWindow) {

    isAnimatingHeaderView = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{

        containerFrame = self.containerView.frame;

        containerFrame.origin.y = -scrollWindow;

        self.containerView.frame = containerFrame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        isAnimatingHeaderView = NO;

        self.lastOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

    }];

}
else  if (self.lastOffset.y > scrollOffset && self.containerView.frame.origin.y < scrollWindow) {

    isAnimatingHeaderView = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{

        containerFrame = self.containerView.frame;

        containerFrame.origin.y = 0;

        self.containerView.frame = containerFrame;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        isAnimatingHeaderView = NO;

        self.lastOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

    }];

}

}
```